# split a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string like ";a;b;c;;e". Notice that there is an extra semicolon before `e`. I want the string to be split in `a`, `b`, `c;`, `e`. But it gets split like `a`, `b`, `c`, `;e`.

My code is

```
var new_arr = str.split(';');
```

What can I do over here to get the result I want?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a Regexp negative lookahead:

```
  ";a;b;c;;e".split(/;(?!;)/)
```

Comment: That is what you stated was your expected outcome.

Comment: See my answer, though.  IE is actually wrong in dropping the first empty element.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, I get `["", "a", "b", "c", "", "e"]` with your code.

```
var new_array = ";a;b;c;;e".split(/;(?!;)/);
new_array.shift();
```

This works in Firefox, but I think it's correct.  You might need this [cross-browser split](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split) for other browsers.

Answer (score -1):

```
var myArr = new Array();

var myString = new String();

myString = ";a;b;c;;e";

myArr = myString.split(";");


for(var i=0;i<myArr.length;i++)
{
    document.write( myArr[i] );
}
```