# JavaScript equivalent of PHP preg_split()

Tags: php, javascript, phpjs

Is there an equivalent of the PHP function [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) for JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript equivalent of php's preg_replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407256/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-preg-replace)

Comment: or a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437919/split-a-string-using-javascript

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Any string in javascript can be split using the [`string.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function, e.g.

```
"foo:bar".split(/:/)
```

where `split` takes as an argument *either* a regular expression or a literal string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions with split.

The problem is the escape characters in the string as the (? opens a non capturing group but there is no corresponding } to close the non capturing group it identifies the string to look for as '

Comment: Meta commentary: this answer is currently terminated at `for as '`. However when I go to edit it I see the whole thing in the preview... huh. Not sure what to do - in the unlikely case a migration or upgrade chewed something somewhere, fixing the comment might mask a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you want support for all of the preg_split arguments see https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/_workbench/pcre/preg_split.js (though not sure how well tested it is).

Just bear in mind that JavaScript's regex syntax is somewhat different from PHP's (mostly less expressive). We would like to integrate [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) at some point as that makes up for some of the missing features of PHP regexes (as well as fixes the many browser reliability problems with functions like String.split()).